# Spring boot Integration test with different database environmets

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, junit4, functional-testing

I have a set of Junit test cases . All test cases have to be executed for different database environments . When using '@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)' in junit test, the spring boot application starts only once . But I need to start the application again with different configurations including flyway migration and other environment related application-<>.properties to run the tests . I have also tried using parameterized tests . In that case too , the spring application gets started only once. Is there any way of achieving this ?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need to use these annotations on your tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Import(MyTestsConfiguration.class)
```

Refer to [this page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html) in the Spring Boot doco for further details

Comment: can you please be more specific

Comment: @Priya Are you using a different class for each time you want the application to start? Adding the first two annotations (and the third, optionally, if you want to override the default configuration) should be all that you need to do.

Comment: Actually I am not runnin different class each time . The class file is the same for all environments. While starting the spring boot application , I will be specifying to use a particular profile to load.

Comment: I'd suggest that you split your tests into separate classes, then. One class = one startup of your application

Comment: Wont it be like duplicating the same test cases again and again

Comment: You could use inheritance to simplify it somewhat - i.e. have a master test class and have your annotated subclasses to do the actual test execution